# How do i detect facebook share and include file if facebook and include file if not

Tags: facebook, redirect

hi i am new to all this

this code works on its own

```
<?php
$pattern = '/(FacebookExternalHit|GoogleBot)/i';
$agent = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_USER_AGENT',      FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED);
if(preg_match($pattern,$agent)){
include 'redirect/facebook.php';
 }
?>
```

but this does not work

```
<?php
$pattern = '/(FacebookExternalHit|GoogleBot)/i';
$agent = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_USER_AGENT',      FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED);
if(preg_match($pattern,$agent)){
include 'redirect/facebook.php';
 } else {
include 'redirect/redirect.php';
}
?>
```

can some one help me with this please

Answer (score 0):

found a php method that works like a charm and and can be added to easily

using this code if some one shares your link on face and you have a country redirect set-up the share will come form the main site as the redirect wont happen when Facebook or Google access your site

```
<?php
$facebook = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"FacebookExternalHit");
$google = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"GoogleBot");

if ($facebook || $google == true) 
{
include 'redirect/facebook.php';
 } else {
 include 'redirect/redirect.php';
 }
?>
```

hope this helps out any one trying to do this easily